# Summer school software courses for middle and high school students?

Tags: education, math-software

I'm willing to teach some software for high school students next summer, I have chosen Mathematica. What other scientific software could I teach to high school students? (Matlab and Maple don't offer much if they know Mathematica).

Does Microsoft Excel offer anything that will help with the teaching of mathematics?

What about middle school students? what should they learn? is [Logo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_%28programming_language%29) suitable for them or for high school students?

Comment: Mathematica is good.

Comment: Mathematica is good (even if its syntax is somewhat messy). [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) and Python-based [Sage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sage_(mathematics_software)) are also worth mentioning, since these are free (and Python could be used for programming tasks). Finally, try looking at [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell), you can find a nice tutorial [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/); it has clean, intuitive syntax, and it might be a good stretch for gifted students (e.g. [here](http://gregheartsfield.com/fractal-hs/)).

Comment: Is [Simulink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulink) too sophisticated?

Answer (score 3):

As a high school maths teacher, it is always welcome to have students literate in various mathematical software applications.

I would suggest t contact the local school authorities and indeed curriculum authorities to see what the curriculum entails and model the software choices on that.  Also, consider the costs of the software compared to its usefulness for the curriculum.

In terms of software, I would recommend [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/), as it covers material of all ages, for geometry, algebra, statistics, and calculus.  Importantly, it is interactive, allowing student exploration of the topics (which would have to be guided).

Hope this helps.